# How can i get the "App Invitable " facebook friends list from ios app?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

In my application , there is a one button that enable after I invite 10 or more friends on facebook.

So how can I get the total number of App Invite counter ?

Comment: You can't access that information - you can only count the successful inviites

Comment: Thank you Nils Ziehn .  But can i get the list of already invited friends? Yes then how ?

Comment: You are not allowed to reward people for _sending_ invites.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find 'my' friends who have installed the app, this would be:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=installed

You can just get the status of that before you send out invites and compare it later how this has changed.

Also, if you don't use app request, but use invite likes, you can track it even better with tools like TapStream.

They provide an iOS framework that allows you to call `getConversionData` which contains information about whether this user clicked a tapstream link to get into your app. You can use a link like this: www.rounak.com/invite/INVITE_ID and use the INVITE_ID to determine by whom the user was invited (and then count this..)

You can find their information about this here:
https://tapstream.com/developer/ios/onboarding-links/

Their service is free unless you have a lot of new users (link clicks)

Comment: NO.. I only want the App Invitable friends list or any ways i want the counter value       i.e.  whatever number of friends i invited